# Showing limit of improper integral using Riemann sum

Tags: integration, limits, riemann-sum

I can show that if $f$ is continuous for $x\ge0$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = A$, then
  \begin{equation}
    \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \! f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t = A
  \end{equation}
using the definition of limits, etc. (a homework question). However, just for my understanding I'm trying to wrap my head around showing the same thing using a Riemann sum.

If I divide the interval of the integral in $n$ parts, each part will be $\frac{x}{n}$ wide. In each such subinterval, I pick the right endpoint: $c_i = \frac{x}{n} \cdot i$ for $i = 1,2,3,\dots,n$.

\begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \int_0^x \! f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t & = A \\
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{i=1}^n f(c_i) \frac{x}{n} &= A \\
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c_i)}{n} x &= A
\end{align}

The $x$ does not depend on $i$ so I can move that out of the summation.

\begin{align}
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} x \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c_i)}{n} &= A \\
  \lim_{x \to \infty} 1 \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(c_i)}{n} &= A
\end{align}

I can see that each $i$ provides an $n$:th contribution to the sum and there's $n$ parts altogether. I can make calculations and see that the sum does converge using various functions for $f$ but I can't quite see why the sum of $f(c_i) = f(\frac{x}{n} \cdot i)$ behaves the way it does when $x\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$.

I hope that was clear enough (first question here! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to prove that 
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nf\left(x\frac jn\right)=A.        $$
Replacing $f$ by $f-A$ (a continuous function which converges to $0$ as $x$ goes to infinity), we only have to treat the case $A=0$. Dealing with $\max\{f,0\}$ and $f-\max\{f,0\}$ successively, we can assume that $f$ is non-negative.

Fix a positive $\delta$. We have 
$$\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^nf\left(x\frac jn\right) \leqslant \delta +\frac 1n\sum_{j=[n\delta]}^nf\left(x\frac jn\right)  \leqslant  \delta +\sup_{
t\geqslant x\delta}f(t), $$
which gives the wanted result.

Comment: It was quite a long time ago that I asked my question so I have to think a while to see if I can grasp your answer. Thanks! : )